# The way for a captain of an airplane to address passengers without mentioning his name

Tags: phrase-request

What's the usual way for a captain of an airplane to address passengers?

Is it like "Hello, captain [family name] is speaking"?

Is it possible to do the same, but without mention the name?

Comment: "This is the Captain speaking. Welcome aboard flight 433 to Toronto." Etc.

Comment: Hawkwind: This Is Your Captain Speaking… Your Captain Is Dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is your/the captain speaking. This is flight XXX to YYY. We will be climbing to a cruising altitude of ZZZ... etc.

I'm not really sure there's any more say about it...